# Conditional formatting: combining multiple checks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Right now I check if a cell is blank, if it is, it becomes red.

```
=ISBLANK($B$12)
```

However this cell only needs to be red when it's empty AND another condition is met: the cell above needs to be set to "YES" or blank.

I tried doing something like:

```
=ISBLANK($B$12),($B$11)=!"NO"
```

But that doesn't really work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [AND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5F19B2E8-E1DF-4408-897A-CE285A19E9D9) can combine the logic in the manner you are looking for.  Try the following,

```
=AND(ISBLANK($B$12), NOT($B$11="NO"))
'or,
=AND($B$12="", $B$11<>"NO")
```

You will likely want to remove the **$** absolute anchor from either the row or column if you want to apply that condition to more than a single cell.

These formulas are applied with the *'Use a formula to determine which cells to format'* option. They are put into the *'Format values where this formula is true:'* text box.

[image: cfr_and]

Comment: Excel won't accept this formula in conditional formatting :/

Comment: Please see the above image that demonstrates both formulas.

Comment: I use dutch so I had to replace AND with EN and NO with NEE

Comment: Oh! OK.. you likely have to use semi-colons as that is the list separator that your computer's regional system is set for. e.g. `=EN($B$12=""; $B$11<>"NO")` and `=EN(ISLEEG($B$12); NIET($B$11="NO"))` (those function translations from the NL-NL language)

Comment: Thanks now excel doesn't give an error! The only frustrating part is that it's not yet working though. The cell is always the default color now, could it be because those cells are selection lists?

Comment: If you mean a data validation list then no, it should not matter. Just tested that. Make sure that B12 is truly blank and not a space.

Comment: turns out I also need to translate the functions inside a conditional formatting formula.. thanks it works now!

Comment: Glad to hear you got sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

You could check for the cell being blank and above being "YES" with the following:

```
=AND(ISBLANK($B$12),EXACT($B$11, "YES"))
```

Comment: Excel won't accept this formula in conditional formatting :/

Comment: Not that it matters too much, but I have given it a test and it does work (you might've been referring to the original version).